# I am following the Wingtip Toys site tutorial from the Microsoft Documentation about ASP .NET web pages but getting a Global.asax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am having issues with a parse error coming up when I go to run the site on the local host domain. I am getting the oddest error, and I was able to fix it by excluding Global.asax from project, but my database for this project is initialized in there.

[Screen Shot of the error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPS4b.png).

I do not know where this issue is coming from, and I cannot find anything about it online.  I know the error is coming from this Global.asax.  I have followed the tutorial closely with the only exception being that I had to convert the C# code to Visual Basic. I am trying to figure this out, but my webpages knowledge does not go this deep.

For those that cannot see the image the error is this:

> Parser Error 'Could not load type "WingtipToys.Global_asax"' Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="WingtipToys.Global_asax" Language="vb" %>

Comment: If you're having a problem with your global.asax, you need to show the relevant code. Show the contents of global.asax.vb. On a side note: why are you learning an outdated framework? Why aren't you learning ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I can't see images. Is it possible to post the text of the error?

Comment: Hey mason and the_lotus, I am using an outdated framework because the shop I am trying to get a job with is hella outdated. The error is  Parser Error 'Could not load type "WingtipToys.Global_asax"' Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="WingtipToys.Global_asax" Language="vb" %>